# How to MASK the Extjs Grid while setting the record data and unmask after set?

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am showing 1500 to 2000 records at a time inside a Grid with 5 columns. There is a combobox on toolbar. When there will be combo change I need to update 2 columns data. For that I am reading the store and setting the values of each record (for 2 columns). Whatever values am setting for 2 columns am getting from another JsonStore.

As there are more than 1000 records its taking sometime to update 2 colums data. Now I am trying to mask the Grid after combo change and unmsak() after all records set.

How to unmask the grid after all records value set?

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Please refer http://jsfiddle.net/alexrom7/kUeU9/4/ and here on combochange I am setting the values of each record from another store.

Answer (score 5):

You can use setLoading() method for that:

```
grid.setLoading(true); // <-- show default load mask to grid
grid.setLoading('some text'); // <-- show load mask with your text
grid.setLoading(false); // <-- hide load mask
```

Comment: updateRecords:function(combo, newValue, oldValue, columnId,statId){
 
 if(oldValue!=undefined){

  grid.setLoading('some text');
  alert("Going to set all records");
  
  var cindex = combo.getValue();
  var column = Ext.getCmp(columnId);
  
  grid.getStore().each(function(record, index, count) {
       var recordDataObject = record.get(statId);
       record.set(columnId, recordDataObject[cindex]);
          });
  }
  grid.setLoading(false);
}

Comment: This works fine but when I am removing alerts its not working at all... means not showing mask and unmask

Comment: @aswininayak Try: `if(index >= grid.getStore().getCount()) grid.setLoading(false);` in cycle. Or show your code in jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks a ton Vlad for your prompt response and help!!

Comment: In case you are expecting a loading mask after a reconfigure on the grid, there is a [bug in ExtJS 4.2](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?263185).  This answer can be used as a workaround.